# Bundler executed in wrong directory when deploying via Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I'm currently trying deploy a rails application to the production server and bundler seems to be executed in the wrong directory

**This is my folder structure**

```
app/
 - Mockups (contains HTML/CSS files)
 - app (contains actuals rails app)
 - (other files)
```

**this is my current cap file**

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**This is my current deploy.rb**

```
# Change these
server '<ip>', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        '<giturl>'
set :application,     'app'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0
set :bundle_gemfile,  "app/Gemfile"
set :bundle_flags,    '--deployment --quiet'

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

My error log indicates when I use `cap production deploy:initial` (or just `deploy` for that matter), that everything works, until it has to execute bundler.

Bundler is being executed inside the "app" folder, which contains subfolders "Mockups" (HTML/CSS), "app" (actual rails app) and other files.

Is there a way to tell bundler it should go one level deeper into the folder in order to execute all bundler related tasks?

Comment: While at first it didn't even find the Gemfile, I was able to fix that myself by adding `set :bundle_gemfile,  "app/Gemfile"`  in my deploy.rb

Comment: Unfortunately this probably just the tip of the iceberg in terms of trouble you will have due to your Rails app not being at the root of your Git repository. The capistrano/rails gem doesn't support this scenario either. Move your app to its own repo if you can.

Comment: @MattBrictson thanks, I moved the rails app to the root of the repo

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you need to set release path otherwise it will not know where the file is.

```
set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('app/Gemfile') }
```